# submit button is not working in Bootstrap contact dorm

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have html, js and php files for contact form, but for some reason form is not responding and not sending emails.
I would appreciate your help.

JS/HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#contact-form [type='submit']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get input field values of the contact form
    var user_name = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var user_email = $('input[name=email-address]').val();
    var user_company = $('input[name=company-name]').val();
    var user_subject = $('input[name=subject]').val();
    var user_message = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    // Datadata to be sent to server
    post_data = {
      'userName': user_name,
      'userEmail': user_email,
      'userCompany': user_company,
      'userSubject': user_subject,
      'userMessage': user_message
    };

    // Ajax post data to server
    $.post('/php/contact-me.php', post_data, function(response) {

      // Load json data from server and output message
      if (response.type == 'error') {

        output = '<div class="error-message"><p>' + response.text + '</p></div>';

      } else {

        output = '<div class="success-message"><p>' + response.text + '</p></div>';

        // After, all the fields are reseted
        $('#contact-form input').val('');
        $('#contact-form textarea').val('');

      }

      $("#answer").hide().html(output).fadeIn();

    }, 'json');

  });

  // Reset and hide all messages on .keyup()
  $("#contact-form input, #contact-form textarea").keyup(function() {
    $("#answer").fadeOut();
  });

});
```

```html
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" data-name="Contact Form">


  <div class="row">

    <!-- Full name -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form form-control" placeholder="Your Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your Name'" name="name" data-name="Name" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- E-mail -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" id="email" class="form form-control" placeholder="Your Email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your Email'" name="email-address" data-name="Email Address" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Company name -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="company" class="form form-control" placeholder="Company name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Company name'" name="company-name" data-name="Company Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Subject -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="subject" class="form form-control" placeholder="Write the subject" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Write the subject'" name="subject" data-name="Subject">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Message -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 no-padding">
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea id="text-area" class="form textarea form-control" placeholder="Your message here... 20 characters Min." onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your message here... 20 characters Min.'" name="message" data-name="Text Area"
          required></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Button submit -->
  <button type="submit" id="valid-form" class="btn btn-color">Send my Message ></button>

</form>
```

and here is php file

```
<?php
if($_POST) {

    $to_Email = "email@gmyemail; // Write your email here

    // Use PHP To Detect An Ajax Request
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        // Exit script for the JSON data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=> 'error',
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    }

    // Checking if the $_POST vars well provided, Exit if there is one missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userSubject"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"])) {

        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<i class="icon ion-close-round"></i> Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }

    // PHP validation for the fields required
    if(empty($_POST["userName"])) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<i class="icon ion-close-round"></i> We are sorry but your name is too short or not specified.'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(!filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<i class="icon ion-close-round"></i> Please enter a valid email address.'));
        die($output);
    }
    // PHP validation for the fields required
    if(empty($_POST["userCompany"])) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<i class="icon ion-close-round"></i> We are sorry but your name is too short or not specified.'));
        die($output);
    }
    // To avoid the spammy bots, you can change the value of the minimum characters required. Here it's <20
    if(strlen($_POST["userMessage"])<20) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<i class="icon ion-close-round"></i> Too short message! Take your time and write a few words.'));
        die($output);
    }

    // Proceed with PHP email
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: My website' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$_POST["userEmail"]."\r\n";

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    // Body of the Email received in your Mailbox
    $emailcontent = 'Hey! You have received a new message from the visitor <strong>'.$_POST["userName"].'</strong><br/><br/>'. "\r\n" .
                'His message: <br/> <em>'.$_POST["userMessage"].'</em><br/><br/>'. "\r\n" .
                '<strong>Feel free to contact '.$_POST["userName"].' via email at : '.$_POST["userEmail"].'</strong>' . "\r\n" ;

    $Mailsending = @mail($to_Email, $_POST["userSubject"], $emailcontent, $headers);

    if(!$Mailsending) {

        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<i class="icon ion-close-round"></i> Oops! Looks like something went wrong, please check your information one more time.'));
        die($output);

    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => '<i class="icon ion-checkmark-round"></i> Hello '.$_POST["userName"] .', Your message has been sent, we will get back to you asap !'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: error : `$to_Email = "email@gmyemail; // Write your email here`

Comment: need more basic debugging details. Is request being made in dev tools network? Any errors thrown? Have you implemented error handling? Take some time to read [ask]

Comment: Here's what I would suggest to get to the answer. First, make sure you're getting inside the jquery click event. You should also use $('').on('click', function() {}); Next, make sure you're getting into the PHP file and that the ajax request works. Look up the best practice for that. Simply just echo out test strings and build the thing piece by piece.

Comment: I would use `$("#contact-form").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();`

Comment: thank you , but already tried, contact form still not responding on submit press or enter

Comment: have you even looked in browser console? Still no mention of errors or if request is being made or if event even fires. Do some basic debugging to at least isolate where problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add jQuery and change to `.on("submit"` of the form, it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#contact-form").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get input field values of the contact form
    var user_name = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var user_email = $('input[name=email-address]').val();
    var user_company = $('input[name=company-name]').val();
    var user_subject = $('input[name=subject]').val();
    var user_message = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    // Datadata to be sent to server
    post_data = {
      'userName': user_name,
      'userEmail': user_email,
      'userCompany': user_company,
      'userSubject': user_subject,
      'userMessage': user_message
    };

    // Ajax post data to server
    $.post('/php/contact-me.php', post_data, function(response) {

      // Load json data from server and output message
      if (response.type == 'error') {

        output = '<div class="error-message"><p>' + response.text + '</p></div>';

      } else {

        output = '<div class="success-message"><p>' + response.text + '</p></div>';

        // After, all the fields are reseted
        $('#contact-form input').val('');
        $('#contact-form textarea').val('');

      }

      $("#answer").hide().html(output).fadeIn();

    }, 'json');

  });

  // Reset and hide all messages on .keyup()
  $("#contact-form input, #contact-form textarea").keyup(function() {
    $("#answer").fadeOut();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" data-name="Contact Form">


  <div class="row">

    <!-- Full name -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form form-control" placeholder="Your Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your Name'" name="name" data-name="Name" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- E-mail -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" id="email" class="form form-control" placeholder="Your Email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your Email'" name="email-address" data-name="Email Address" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Company name -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="company" class="form form-control" placeholder="Company name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Company name'" name="company-name" data-name="Company Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Subject -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="subject" class="form form-control" placeholder="Write the subject" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Write the subject'" name="subject" data-name="Subject">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Message -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 no-padding">
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea id="text-area" class="form textarea form-control" placeholder="Your message here... 20 characters Min." onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your message here... 20 characters Min.'" name="message" data-name="Text Area"
          required></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Button submit -->
  <button type="submit" id="valid-form" class="btn btn-color">Send my Message ></button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I missed to include <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: right now js validate form but no connecting to php, do you know what could be a cause , i checked a path and its working

Comment: Look  in the network tab. If you look in the network tab in my example you will see SO blocks submission but the post is happening

Comment: i looked under network on my website and nginx  showing error : HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 10 Apr 2017 22:25:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 584
Connection: keep-alive .                                                                          
Could you advice me how to fix, im also using Digital Ocean server.thank  you

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a syntax error in your PHP code

```
$to_Email = "email@gmyemail; // Write your email here
```

It should change to `$to_Email = "email@gmyemail"; // Write your email here`
BTW, if it's not the issue, Please enable PHP debug mode and check the error logs. This may help you to find the issue.

Comment: email is not a problem(i changed it), form is not even responding on submit button click or enter